# Is possible to change URL according to what section is currently active with Svelte?

Tags: jquery, url, scroll, svelte, sveltekit

My one page website has multiple sections. Is there a way to change the URL when I scroll to dedicated section? The URL changes when I reach the section by clicking on anchor, but not when scrolling. Im working with SvelteKit.

I've tried some jQuery, but I can't figure out how to combine it with SvelteKit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can e.g. use an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), either standalone or in conjunction with actions. With actions you can more easily attach the functionality to a given node, e.g. a heading.

Here would be a basic example that can be applied to individual headings:

```js
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

export function autoHash(node) {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
        threshold: 1,
    });

    observer.observe(node);

    function callback(entries) {
        const entry = entries.find(entry => entry.isIntersecting);

        if (entry) {
            const id = entry.target.id;
            goto(`#${id}`, { replaceState: true, noScroll: true });
        }
    };

    return { destroy: () => observer.disconnect() };
}
```

Usage:

```html
<script>
    import { autoHash } from './auto-hash';
</script>

<h3 id="some-section" use:autoHash>Section Title</h3>
```